# What's the best way to find a control in a form when using caliburn.micro?

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, find, caliburn.micro

Is there a good way to find a named control in a form from the ViewModel when using Caliburn.Micro? Does the IoC provide any way to get at the form?

Answer (score 5):

You can override `AttachView` or `OnViewLoaded` in your view model (part of the `Screen` type), which Caliburn.Micro passes the view to, e.g for a button control:

```
public override void AttachView(object view, object context)
{
  base.AttachView(view, context);

  var frameworkElement = view as FrameworkElement;

  if (frameworkElement == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  var button = frameworkElement.FindName("myButton") as Button;

  if (button == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  // access button control here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call GetView() from the view model also.  Then search for the control or access it by name.